# freading from a file that was fclosed before reading

Tags: c++, fopen, fread, fclose

I spend a sleepless night yesterday trying to track down a bug in my test case. My interface looks something like this:

```cpp
image read_image(FILE *file) {
  if (file == nullptr) {
    //throw exception 
  }
  //call ftell and fread on the file
  //but not fclose
  ...
  //return an image
}
```

Turns out one of my test cases tested whether my code can handle reading from a file that was first opened (so the file pointer was not `nullptr`), but closed before I pass it to my function, something like this:

```
FILE *img_file = fopen("existing_image.png", "r");
REQUIRE(img_file != nullptr); //this passes!
fclose(img_file);
auto my_image = image_read(file);

//... then somewhere down in completely
//unrelated test cases I get segfaults,
//double free errors and the like
```

Then I spent hours trying to track down segfaults, double frees in completely unrelated parts of my code until I removed that particular test case. This seemed to solve it.

My questions are:

1. I know calling `fread`/`ftell` on a closed file is a dumb idea but could it really cause that kind of memory corruption? I looked around on e.g. cppreference but it was never explicitly specified that passing a closed stream is undefined behavior...
2. Is there any way of finding out if a file was closed before reading from it? (I looked on SO, but the answer seems: no.)

**Additional Info**

I am using C++17 and gcc 9.3.0 to compile. The reason I have to deal with `FILE *` at all is because I am receiving these pointers from an external C API.

Comment: Using any `f*` function (`ftell`, `fread`, etc.) on a FILE pointer that has been closed previously or any other invalid FILE pointer is undefined bahyviour.

Comment: are you checking fread and ftell return values?

Comment: To prevent that kind of problems it's usual (for some values of "usual") to set the pointer to `NULL` ... ie `fclose(pointer); pointer = NULL;` (same idea as in `free(pointer); pointer = NULL;`)

Comment: `it was never explicitly specified that passing a closed stream is undefined behavior` "Undefined" means... not defined, so if it's not defined your best bet is that it means it's undefined. Anyway in [annex j2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) it's plain `The value of a pointer to a FILE object is used after the associated file is closed`

Comment: Can I withdraw money from a bank account I've closed?

Comment: If you want some more safety use `std::fstream` which has a closed state

Comment: @tadman Will the bank explode or will someone politely tell you that your account is closed? ;)

Comment: "_I am receiving these pointers from an external C API_" - Are you also receiving ownership of the `FILE*`? If you do, store it in a smart-pointer, like `struct fcloser { auto operator()(std::FILE* fp) const { return std::fclose(fp); } };` and then `std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, fcloser> file;`

Comment: Yes, i did that. But that only helps if the file was not closed to begin with.

Comment: @geo If you own the pointer there's _no_ need to test what happens if you close it when you shouldn't. Your smart pointer owns the `FILE*` and noone else should be closing it.

Comment: ... and if someone still does, make your own RAII wrapper around it and only provide methods to use it as intended without providing access to the raw `FILE*` itself.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  Sorry, I was not clear. I don't create the FILE pointer but I am responsible for closing it. So somebody else calls fopen. The strategy you mentioned helps me prevent a double free in my own code (and guarantees fclose even in case of exceptions) but unfortunately won't help me when somebody passes in a closed file pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - I know calling `fread/ftell` on a closed file is a dumb idea but could it really cause that kind of memory corruption? I looked around on e.g. cppreference but it was never explicitly specified that passing a closed stream is undefined behavior...

Trying `fread` or `ftell` on a `FILE*` that's been closed will make both functions return -1 and set `errno` to an appropriate value on *many* systems - but you can usually avoid this by checking if the `FILE*` is valid.

> - Is there any way of finding out if a file was closed before reading from it? (I looked on SO, but the answer seems: no.)

In Posix systems and Windows (and possibly others), yes. Posix `fileno()` and Windows `_fileno()` returns -1 if the argument isn't a valid stream, like after it's been closed.

You could therefore create a RAII wrapper that takes ownership of the `FILE*` and checks if it's valid at construction. If it passes this test, the risk of anything in *your* code closing it when it's not supposed to will be very low.

Here's an outline of such a wrapper:

```
class File {
public:
    File(std::FILE* fp) : file(validate(fp)) {
        if(!file) throw std::runtime_error("I don't like nullptr");
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    auto read(T(&buf)[N], std::size_t nmemb = N) {
        if(N < nmemb) throw std::runtime_error("reading out of bounds");
        return fread(buf, sizeof(T), nmemb, file.get());
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    auto write(const T(&buf)[N], std::size_t nmemb = N) {
        if(N < nmemb) throw std::runtime_error("writing out of bounds");
        return fwrite(buf, sizeof(T), nmemb, file.get());
    }

private:
    std::FILE* validate(std::FILE* fp) {
#if defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
        if(::fileno(fp) == -1) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
#elif defined(_WIN32)
        if(::_fileno(fp) == -1) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
#endif
        return fp;
    }
    struct fcloser {
        auto operator()(std::FILE* fp) const {
            return std::fclose(fp); 
        } 
    };

    std::unique_ptr<FILE, fcloser> file;
};
```

It'd need seeking / telling member functions etc. too, but this should keep your pointer reasonably safe.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3fno1j)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can cause memory corruption because a `FILE *` might have allocated memory. Probably using `malloc`.

What happens to your program if you try to use a pointer from `malloc` after you used `free` on it?

Yes, everything breaks. Do not do that.

Answer (score 2):

The power and efficiency of the C and C++ languages come with great responsibility: the programmer must be cautious about the life cycle or every object.

C++ make this easier with smart pointers and [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), but C lacks these paradigms so every pointer is a potential source of undefined behavior. Pointers received from C APIs are a good example.

You could set the `FILE *` to `NULL` after every `fclose` but this will not solve the problem if the `FILE` pointer was received as an argument or duplicated some other way.

There is no standard API to check if a pointer is valid, nor in this particular case if a `FILE *` refers to an open stream. To make things worse, `FILE` pointers are usually recycled quickly, so a stale `FILE *` may very well refer to a newly open file, different from the one for which it was originally received.

Comment: Yes, this is my problem precisely. If I already received a closed FILE pointer from the get go it seems I am screwed...